# Shared element back animation without backstack

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I use one activity multiple fragments in my app. I use a shared element animation. I have two fragments, one of them is a detail page.

I don't want to addToBackStack function for fragment transition. And the detail fragment returns without animation for some cases. **(fragmentMain->fragmentDetail)**

```java
DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
Transition moveTransition = TransitionInflater.from(MainActivity.singleInstance)
            .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move); // android.R.transition.move
moveTransition.setDuration(400);

detailFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(moveTransition);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.getActivityFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(sharedView, sharedView.getTransitionName())
            .replace(R.id.mainLayout, detailFragment);

fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

This code works for me. I know that if I use `addToBackStack`, **fragmentDetail->fragmentMain** reveal animation works automatically. But I don't want to the use back stack.

Below code doesn't works for **fragmentDetail->fragmentMain.**

```java
detailFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(moveTransition);
mainFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(moveTransition);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.getActivityFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(textView, textView.getTransitionName())
            .replace(R.id.mainLayout, mainFragment);

fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

How can I do shared element animation for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your onCreateView function. If It recreate the layout, it breaks the transition id.

Solution:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if(inflatedView != null)
        return inflatedView;
    inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, 
    return inflatedView;
}
```